# Which language to use to parse xml for navigation

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have written some php code to parse a xml file already with SimpleXML,  its pretty messy, but can include if that helps.

This is what the xml file looks like (navigation file, thats been done really weirdly and can't be changed)

```
    <root name="menutest">
      <menu>
          <nav name="home" path="index.php" />

          <nav name="menulink1" path="link1.php">
              <nav name="menulink1child1" path="menulink1childlink1.php">
                 <nav name="menulink1child1child1"
                      path="menulink1childlink1childlink1.php" />
              </nav>
          </nav>

          <nav name="menulink2" path="link2.php">
             <nav name="menulink1child2" path="menulink2childlink2.php">
                <nav name="menulink2child2child2"
                     path="menulink2childlink2childlink2.php" />
             </nav>
          </nav>

          <nav name="menulink3" path="link3.php">
             <nav name="menulink3child3" path="menulink3childlink3.php">
                 <nav name="menulink3child3child3"
                      path="menulink3childlink3childlink3.php" />
             </nav>
          </nav>

          <nav name="menulink4" path="link4.php">
             <nav name="menulink4child4"
                  path="menulink4childlink4.php">
                 <nav name="menulink4child4child4"
                   path="menulink4childlink4childlink4.php" />
             </nav>
          </nav>
      </menu>
  </root>
```

I was thinking using just SimpleXML to parse and XPATH to select nodes and then using the page URL using $_SERVER requests so I could detect what menu item should be open to use the right css styles e.g. add style to nav name="menulink1child1child1. 
**Note** that only tier 1 nav elements should be selected for top level pages and subsequent child elements when they go into child pages of that element

i.e.

```
 homepage:  home | menulink1 | menulink2| menulink3 | menulink4 | 
 menulink1: menulink1 
            -- childlink1 
            | menulink2 | menulink3 | menulink4
```

**Note** that menu is vertical, not horizontal, so child elements need to appear in the right order of the parent elements, not just automatically below on a new row of the webpage :)

My question is; what is the best way to parse an xml navigation file that requires conditions to select the children elements? Should I be looking at using XSL to transform the xml?

TIA
Jared

Comment: Have you looked into SimpleXML?

Comment: @Darren Yes thats what I have been using to parse the xml, but I'm finding it difficult to traverse to the correct nodes when a user goes to a certain level of the site.

Comment: @Jared: This question is not clear... For parsing you need a parser, of course. For selecting, you could use XPath. But you are talking about a web page and the process from this XML document to the web page is not clear. Plus, it looks like you are asking about CSS rules for building a menu.

Comment: @Alejandro fair enough, I'll try and update it better

Comment: Have you tried PHP DOMDocument?

Comment: p.s thanks for all the edits on my shoddy xml code ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's worth the investment in learning XSLT. It's a language that some people find off-putting at first sight, and many give up before they've mastered it, but once you've sussed it, it works really well for this kind of problem, and can be used both server-side and client-side.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I've been looking at xsl over the last few days and I definitely think this is the way to go down and as a bonus its something new to learn with XML. Cheers guys.