# how to traverse xml file based on variables with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I recently asked a question on which engine to parse my xml and decided to stick to XSL, but I can only get the job half done. (ref: [Which language to use to parse xml for navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891692/which-language-to-use-to-parse-xml-for-navigation))

I've managed to get as far as traversing down `<root> --> <menu> --> <nav>` but any children under nav and my logic gets totally screwed up.

Question is how do I repeat my logic in xsl to go deeper in the xml child nodes, when the @path is the next child node tier?

Am I even doing this right? I feel like I'm missing something here and should be using templates somehow?

For example here is my xsl style sheet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    Document   : sitemap.xsl
    Created on : 2 February 2011, 14:53
    Author     : Jared
    Description:
        Purpose of transformation follows.
-->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" />
    <xsl:param name="page" select="default"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <ul class="level-0 top-level">
            <xsl:for-each select="*/nav">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$page = '/index.aspx'">
                        <!-- level 0 -->
                        <li>
                            <a><xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="@path" /></xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></a>
                        </li>
                    </xsl:when>

                    <xsl:when test="@path=$page and $page != '/index.aspx'">
                        <!-- level 2 -->
                        <li class="children-open current-menu-page">
                            <a><xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="@path" /></xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></a>
                            <ul class="level-2 current-menu">
                                <xsl:for-each select="/root/menu/nav[@path=$page]/child::*">
                                    <li>
                                        <a><xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="@path" /></xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="@name" /><br /></a>
                                    </li>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </xsl:when>


                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <li>
                            <a><xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="@path" /></xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></a>
                        </li>
                    </xsl:otherwise>


                </xsl:choose>

            </xsl:for-each>

        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML file looks something like this:

```
<root name="menutest">
  <menu>
      <nav name="home" path="index.php" />

      <nav name="menulink1" path="link1.php">
          <nav name="menulink1child1" path="menulink1childlink1.php">
             <nav name="menulink1child1child1"
                  path="menulink1childlink1childlink1.php" />
          </nav>
      </nav>

      <nav name="menulink2" path="link2.php">
         <nav name="menulink1child2" path="menulink2childlink2.php">
            <nav name="menulink2child2child2"
                 path="menulink2childlink2childlink2.php" />
         </nav>
      </nav>

      <nav name="menulink3" path="link3.php">
         <nav name="menulink3child3" path="menulink3childlink3.php">
             <nav name="menulink3child3child3"
                  path="menulink3childlink3childlink3.php" />
         </nav>
      </nav>

      <nav name="menulink4" path="link4.php">
         <nav name="menulink4child4"
              path="menulink4childlink4.php">
             <nav name="menulink4child4child4"
               path="menulink4childlink4childlink4.php" />
         </nav>
      </nav>
  </menu>
</root>
```

This basically only shows first tier `<nav>` children based on param "$page".
Example(s) of how the menu works and which nodes selected, basically aligned `<nav>` nodes are children, indented nodes are child of parents and so on etc etc. [xml example http://fraudo.orconhosting.net.nz/xml.png](http://fraudo.orconhosting.net.nz/xml.png)

TIA
Jared

Updated code snippet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" />
    <xsl:param name="page" select="'index.aspx'"/>

    <xsl:template name="makeUL">
        <ul class="level-2 current-menu">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="nav">

            <li>
            <xsl:if test=".//@path = $page and $page != '/index.aspx'">
                <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:text>children-open current-menu-page</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
             </xsl:if>
            <a href="{@path}">
                <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
            </a>
            <xsl:if test=".//@path = $page and $page != '/index.aspx'">
                 <xsl:call-template name="makeUL"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </li>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I also echo out "ul" before the xml parsing, but I may have that wrong :).

```
echo '<ul class="level-0 top-level">'."\n\r";
    echo $xsl->transformToXML($dom);
echo '</ul>'."\n\r";
```

Comment: This is very unclear. Please, provide a complete (but minimal) example: The source XML document, the complete wanted results, and any rules that the transformation must implement.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev, Hi Dimitre, thanks for taking time to look at my question, I've updated it with more examples, hopefully this makes things more clear. TIA.

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you are asking for. Do you want to expand the branch of the identified node?

Comment: @Alejandro Yes thats right I want to expand the nodes based on the param (which is the @path attribute of child nodes). I think your answer is setting me on right course though as @Michael Kay pointed out, I want to do it the "xslt way". Tyvm for helping me guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to expand the branch of tree containing the identified node, this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" />
    <xsl:param name="page" select="'menulink1childlink1.php'"/>
    <xsl:template match="menu" name="makeUL">
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="nav">
        <li>
            <a href="{@path}">
                <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
            </a>
            <xsl:if test=".//@path = $page">
                <xsl:call-template name="makeUL"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="link1.php">menulink1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="menulink1childlink1.php">menulink1child1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="menulink1childlink1childlink1.php"
                          >menulink1child1child1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="link2.php">menulink2</a></li>
    <li><a href="link3.php">menulink3</a></li>
    <li><a href="link4.php">menulink4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Rendered:

- home
- menulink1

  - menulink1child1

    - menulink1child1child1
- menulink2
- menulink3
- menulink4

**Note:** This is the only case where `.//` abbreviation can be handy.

Comment: @Alejandro Thanks, thats doing it, I've included update on that code snippet so you could see what I'm trying to do. You've put me in the right direction now so I feel I can finish this now, tyvm.

Comment: @Jared: I didn't add those `@class` because it wasn't clear. Should it be: first `ul` *level-0 top-level*, every other *level-2 current-menu*; `li` in the open branch (including ancestors) *children-open current-menu-page*?

Comment: @Alejandro yup first ul is level-0, I'm sorry if I wasn't clear obviously I know it too well to explain it properly :) second tier children ul should be level-2 and so on and so on. But your answer was really helpful and I think I can handle the rest, unless you want to add something to your original answer, tyvm :)

Answer (score 2):

The root cause of your trouble is that you are trying to use "pull" processing - traditional constructs like xsl:for-each and xsl:choose, instead of writing it "the XSLT way" using template rules and xsl:apply-templates. It's usually possible to write your code in "pull" style, but experts avoid it because it tends to lead you into this kind of trouble.

I say "usually", but one case where it isn't possible is when your input data is recursive (nav elements within nav elements, indefinitely nested). You can only process recursive data using recursive code, and in this situation, the apply-templates style of coding becomes essential. Sit down with a tutorial and read some examples until you have understood the concept, and then use it in your coding.